# OpenFileDialog return an exception when it is empty

Tags: c#, winforms, openfiledialog

```
bool gGender = false;

if (radioBtnMale.Checked == true)
   gGender = true;

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtboxName.Text))
{
    if (imageToByteArray(Image.FromFile(openFileDialogPhoto.FileName)) == null)
    {
        repository.WorkflowsRepository.AddEmployee(txtboxName.Text, dateTimePickerBirthDate.Value, dateTimePickerHireDate.Value, gGender, txtboxMobile.Text, txtboxAddress.Text, txtboxEmail.Text,null);
    }

    repository.WorkflowsRepository.AddEmployee(txtboxName.Text, dateTimePickerBirthDate.Value, dateTimePickerHireDate.Value, gGender, txtboxMobile.Text, txtboxAddress.Text, txtboxEmail.Text, imageToByteArray(Image.FromFile(openFileDialogPhoto.FileName)));

    Information WFNameInfo = new Information("Massege", "The Employee " + txtboxName.Text + " was Added successfully");
    WFNameInfo.ShowDialog();
}
else
{
    Error err = new Error("The Employee must have a name, please try again");
    err.ShowDialog();
}
```

In this example I want to add an employee, but when an employee don't have a photo I mean the `OpenFileDialog` don't have any value it returns an exception at add operation.

I need to be able to add an employee without a photo!!

Comment: show your code,please

Comment: Help us help you. We can't help you if you don't add your code. How else are we supposed to see what the problem is? You also need to show us the **full exception message**

Comment: if your image is null you're adding the employee twice

Comment: Are you calling the `openFileDialogPhoto.ShowDialog()` in another event and then setting the file name in the `txtboxName.Text`?

Comment: Yes I called from anther method

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is the lack of an else statement :

```
if (imageToByteArray(Image.FromFile(openFileDialogPhoto.FileName)) == null)
{
    repository.WorkflowsRepository.AddEmployee(txtboxName.Text, dateTimePickerBirthDate.Value, dateTimePickerHireDate.Value, gGender, txtboxMobile.Text, txtboxAddress.Text, txtboxEmail.Text,null);
}
 repository.WorkflowsRepository.AddEmployee(txtboxName.Text, dateTimePickerBirthDate.Value, dateTimePickerHireDate.Value, gGender, txtboxMobile.Text, txtboxAddress.Text, txtboxEmail.Text, imageToByteArray(Image.FromFile(openFileDialogPhoto.FileName)));
```

if (imageToByteArray() == null) you are still executing the second statement.  Try:

```
if (imageToByteArray(Image.FromFile(openFileDialogPhoto.FileName)) == null)
{
    repository.WorkflowsRepository.AddEmployee(txtboxName.Text, dateTimePickerBirthDate.Value, dateTimePickerHireDate.Value, gGender, txtboxMobile.Text, txtboxAddress.Text, txtboxEmail.Text,null);
}
else
{
    repository.WorkflowsRepository.AddEmployee(txtboxName.Text, dateTimePickerBirthDate.Value, dateTimePickerHireDate.Value, gGender, txtboxMobile.Text, txtboxAddress.Text, txtboxEmail.Text, imageToByteArray(Image.FromFile(openFileDialogPhoto.FileName)));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Problem :** You are not calling `openFileDialogPhoto.ShowDialog()` and trying to access the `openFileDialogPhoto.FileName` which is ofcourse `null`.

**Solution:** You should call the `openFileDialogPhoto.ShowDialog()` and also should only proceed further if the user selects the File.you can check this by `DialogResult` return value ,before accessing the its `FileName` property.

Try This:

```
if(openFileDialogPhoto.ShowDialog()==DialogResult.OK)
{
   if (imageToByteArray(Image.FromFile(openFileDialogPhoto.FileName)) == null)
   {
     repository.WorkflowsRepository.AddEmployee(txtboxName.Text, dateTimePickerBirthDate.Value, dateTimePickerHireDate.Value, gGender, txtboxMobile.Text, txtboxAddress.Text, txtboxEmail.Text,null);
   }
   repository.WorkflowsRepository.AddEmployee(txtboxName.Text, dateTimePickerBirthDate.Value, dateTimePickerHireDate.Value, gGender, txtboxMobile.Text, txtboxAddress.Text, txtboxEmail.Text, imageToByteArray(Image.FromFile(openFileDialogPhoto.FileName)));
   Information WFNameInfo = new Information("Massege", "The Employee " + txtboxName.Text + " was Added successfully");
   WFNameInfo.ShowDialog();
}
```